# Setting up a Python web development environment on OS X

Tags: python, mysql, apache, macos

I'm running [Mac OS X Leopard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Leopard) and wanted to know what the easy way to setup a web development environment to use Python, MySQL, Apache on my machine which would allow me to develop on my Mac and then easily move it to a host in the future.

I've been trying to get mod_wsgi installed and configured to work with Django and have a headache now. Are there any web hosts that currently use mod_wsgi besides Google, so I could just develop there?

Comment: For the record, Google hasn't got anything to do with mod_wsgi. The mod_wsgi projects code happens to be hosted on Google Code site, but that is the only relationship to Google, they otherwise have nothing to do with it and are not known to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Most Python applications are moving away from mod_python. It can vary by framework or provider, but most development effort is going into mod_wsgi.

Using the [WSGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface) standard will make your Python application server agnostic, and allow for other nice additions like WSGI middleware. Other providers may only provide [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) (which won't scale well performance wise), or [FastCGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI).

Comment: Agree, built it with WSGI and you can happily run it on all the interfaces mentioned so far, mod_wsgi, mod_python, CGI, even GAE with limitations.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, we've found virtualenv [http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv] to be an invaluable part of our dev setup. We typically work on multiple projects that use different versions of Python libraries etc. It's very difficult to do this on one machine without some way to provide a localized, customized Python environment, as virtualenv does.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) using only the included server in the `manager.py` script and have not had any trouble moving to a production environment.

If you put your application in a host that does the environment configuration for you (like [WebFaction](https://www.webfaction.com/)) you should not have problems moving from development to production.

Answer (score 1):

I run a Linux virtual machine on my Mac laptop. This allows me to keep my development environment and production environments perfectly in sync (and make snapshots for easy experimentation / rollback). I've found [VMWare Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/download/fusion/) works the best, but there are free open source alternatives such as [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) if you just want to get your feet wet.

I share the source folders from the guest Linux operating system on my Mac and edit them with the Mac source editor of my choosing (I use [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) / [PyDev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyDev) because the otherwise excellent [TextMate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextMate) doesn't deal well with Chinese text yet). I've documented the software setup for the guest Linux operating system [here](http://wiki.slicehost.com/doku.php?id=dream_geodjango_server); it's optimized for serving multiple [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) applications (including geodjango).

For extra added fun, you can edit your Mac's /etc/hosts file to make yourdomainname.com resolve to your guest Linux boxes internal IP address and have a simple way to work on / test multiple web projects online or offline without too much hassle.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is Mod_Python.  It's an Apache-based interpreter for Python.  Check it out here:

http://www.modpython.org/

Comment: more like mod_wscgi. mod_python is generally considered too low-level for web development.

Answer (score 0):

[Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) has done it for you.  Some limitations but it works great, and it gives you a path to hosting free.

Answer (score 0):

Of course Mac OS X, in recent versions, comes with Python and Apache.  However you may want to have more flexibility in the versions you use, or you may not like the tweaks Apple has made to the way they are configured.  A good way to get a more generic set of tools, including MySQL, is to install them anew.  This will help your portability issues.  The frameworks can be installed relatively easily with one of these open source package providers.

- [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/)
- [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/)
- [MAMP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mamp)

Comment: I've looked into MAMP before, is there any way to get mod_wsgi to work with it?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [web2py](http://www.web2py.com). It includes an administration interface to develop via your browser. All you need in one package, including [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [WebFaction](http://www.webfaction.com)—although I don't use them (nor am I related to / profit from their business in any way). I've read over and over how great their service is and particularly how [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29)-friendly they are. There's a specific [post in their forums](http://forum.webfaction.com/viewtopic.php?id=1119) about getting up and running with Django and `mod_wsgi`.

Like others before me in this thread, I highly recommend using Ian Bicking's [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) to isolate your development environment; there's a [dedicated page in the `mod_wsgi` documentation](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments) for exactly that sort of setup.

I'd also urge you to check out [pip](http://pip.openplans.org/), which is basically a smarter easy_install which knows about virtualenv. Pip does two really nice things for virtualenv-style development:

- Knows how to install from source control ([SVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion), [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29), etc...)
- Knows how to "freeze" an existing development environement's requirements so that you can create that environment somewhere else—very very nice for multiple developers or deployment.

Answer (score 0):

`mod_wsgi` is really, really simple.

[Pyerweb](http://github.com/dbr/pyerweb/blob/070e354c1837e7d22a8bd5160d7f0897391bf382/pyerweb.py#L64) is a really simple (~90 lines including comments/whitespace) WSGI-compliant routing-framework I wrote. Basically the WSGI API is just a function that gets passed `environ`, and `wsgi_start_response`, and it returns a string.

`envrion` is a dict with the request info, for example `environ['PATH_INFO']` is the request URI)

`wsgi_start_response` which is a callable function which you execute to set the headers,:

```
wsgi_start_response(output_response, output_headers)
```

`output_response` is the string containing the HTTP status you wish to send (`200 OK` etc), and `output_headers` is a list-of-tuples containing your headers (for example, `[("Content-type", "text/html")]` would set the content-type)

Then the function returns a string containing your output.. That's all there is to it!

To run it, using [`spawning`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Spawning/0.7) you can just do `spawn scriptname.my_wsgi_function_nae` and it will start listening on port 8080.

To use it via mod_wsgi, it's documentation is good, http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide and there is a [django specific section](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango)

The up-side to using mod_wsgi is it's the standard for serving Python web-applications. I recently decided to play with Google App Engine, and was surprised when Pyerweb (which I linked to at the start of this answer) worked *perfectly* on it, completely unintentionally. I was even more impressed when I noticed Django applications run on it too.. Standardisation is a good thing!